# build a delphi 7 project with MSBuild

Tags: delphi, msbuild

I try to use MSBuild to build a delphi project, but the problem that in the version 7 of delphi, there is no file with the extension .dproj
is there any solution allow me to build it using MSBuild ?

Comment: Sure it can be done. But you'll need to define your own schema.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi 7 did not produce the XML project files used by MS-Build. In order to use MS-Build to build Delphi 7 projects, you'd have to generate your own .dproj file in the proper format.

It also did not come with the Borland assemblies necessary for use with MS-Build (which were placed in the `%WINDIR%\assembly\GAC_MSIL` folder in  more recent Delphi installations), so you'd have to create your own schema that calls the Delphi compiler (both code and resource).

Comment: can you tell me what I have to do regarding the second problem please ?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't, because I've never needed to do it. I haven't used D7 for decades now. The oldest version I still have around is D2007, which supports MS-Build and has the proper format XML .dproj files.

Comment: I'm sure you don't need those assemblies. You can create a schema that invokes dcc32.

Comment: @David: Clarified what I meant in the second paragraph (which was better stated by your phrasing). Thanks.